# JQuery CSS Use a "height: auto;" as a "margin-bottom" for another element

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic, footer

I have a footer with its height set to "auto". Now, I want the site container's margin-bottom to be the same as the height of the footer (dynamically).
How?

HTML:

```
<div id="footer" class="arial">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>            
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:#3498db;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 15pt;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#container').css('margin-bottom', $('#footer').height());
```

Obviously this should only be run after the page is loaded, or else it will have all the wrong values.